# Some secret codes not working after installing CyanogenMod

Tags: cyanogenmod, mac-address

I installed CyanogenMod on my Galaxy SIII I9300, There was a secret code that shows MAC address of the device: `*#232338#` that was working when original stock ROM was on my device. But it does not works now. Is the secret code list differs between original stock ROM and CyanogenMod? If yes, where I could find new secret code list?

Comment: Such secret codes are usually not needed on a custom ROM like CM, because their functionality is easy to access via `Settings` or a menu inside. "Secret codes" are usually only GSM codes (working on *every* phone) or "shortcuts".

Comment: For you: Go to `Settings->About the phone->Status` scroll down to `Wifi MAC address` and read it there.

Answer (score 1):

Some "secret" codes are provided via hidden apps that the carrier and/or the device manufacturer installs in the phone's firmware. When you switch to a custom ROM such as Cyanogenmod, those apps are no longer present.

Nevertheless, for just about anything you might have wanted a "secret" code for, there is some way to get that information already, either through an existing menu item or a free app you can find on the Play Store.

Answer (score 0):

In CyanogenMod 12, it's **Settings**->**WiFi**->**Advanced WiFi** (in the menu) and there you can find both IPv4 and IPv6 MACs.

Or, to find it in the command line, say via adb, type `adb shell netcfg`.  Also you can use `adb shell ip addr show` from the command line which also gives you this info.  Both of these commands can also be entered via the Terminal app and neither requires root.

(On some older devices you can try using `ifconfig -a` or even `iwconfig -a`... good luck!)

Answer (score 0):

Try this Code,

```
*#*#232338#*#*
```

Here is a List:

WiFi Mac Address Secret Code:

```
*#*#232338#*#*
```

Bluetooth Test Code :

```
*#*#232331#*#*
```

Bluetooth Device Address :

```
*#*#232337#*#*
```

Power Off Code :

```
*#*#7594#*#*
```

Quick GPS Test Code :

```
*#*#1472365#*#*
```

Different GPS Test Code :

```
*#*#1575#*#*
```

This list will be long, find the rest [here](http://technofizi.com/android-secret-codes/)